# Response.Write in user control doesn't effect all page but usercontrol only

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

How do I use `Response.Write` in user control to response all page not just user control itself?

```
function genericAjax(url, data) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: data,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if(data.d == "refresh")
            {
                location.reload();
            } 
        }
    });
}
```

PageLoad

```
if(Request.Form["ajax"])
{
    //some code
    Response.Write("refresh");
}
```

Comment: Please clarify? _Typically_ a UserControl "encapsulate" things (to itself). You can obtain references to its [`Parent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.parent(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I checked parent but Its relative how many levels I should go up to top

Comment: Usually, you should not use Response.Write in ASP.NET. Instead, put a control (e.g. an `<asp:Literal>`) where you want the output to appear and use that to display whatever.

Comment: Its an ajax requests response, I am using page as a responder because WebMethods doesn't work in user controls. I don't need content of page but json return.

Comment: Please would you edit your question to explain what is requesting data from what, and what event causes the data to be requested, so that we can see what is meant to be happening client-side and server-side.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but is what you are trying to do the same as an ordinary HTML <form> submit?

Comment: yeah you can say that